# mysqldump backup is missing all innodb tables but not MyISAM tables

Tags: innodb, mysql

Here are the switches I'm using with mysqldump to backup my database:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u **** --password=**** --single-transaction --database ****  > /filepath/filename.sql
```

I'm importing into my local database using windows (server is linux) with:

```
mysql -u root 

use databasename

source c:/filepath/filename.sql
```

when I compare the server database verse the local, innodb tables are missing, below is the result of 'show engines;' on the local database:

[image: show engines]

Comment: Can you find your missing tables in the file `/filepath/filename.sql` when you open it with a text editor? Show the output of `show engines`, maybe INNODB is disabled.

Comment: I've edited the show engines result into the original post, I may need to get back to you with the contents of .sql the file is over a gigabyte, sublime will load it eventually but it's going to take a while

Comment: Which version of mysql are you using (on Windows)?

Comment: Server version: 5.5.27 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: kind of surprised that this is happened and no one seems to have an idea why :S seems like a fairly big failing - so something that people would be aware of

Comment: Can you grep your filename.sql file to see if the InnoDB table definition and contents are there?

Comment: I've not used grep before but I will give it ago today and hopefully get back to you

Comment: okay so the .sql file contains commands that drop one of the innodb tables and recreates it, repopulating the table contents, proving it has saved at least one of the innodb tables

Answer (score 0):

It could be the `--single-transaction` option.  Is it possible that you're altering the table while you did the dump?  If so the `alter table` would be done outside of the transaction.  It will create a temporary table, drop the original and rename the temp table.  Since the original table is "gone", it will not be put in the dump file.

You can try using --lock-tables instead and see if that works.

Comment: --single-transaction was added to try and solve this problem, the same problems existed without the switch, the table structure is not altered during backup periods :(

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this in the end by wiping the local database entirely and then reloading the database from the backup, not sure why the local database was not displaying innodb tables but it's fixed